# Eclipse e4 : ModeledPageLayout `getFolderForView(String)` doesn't seem to work

Tags: eclipse, model, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I previously used Eclipse Indigo (3.7) and currently I'm running my 3.x sources on top of e4 (compatibility mode).

When running my 3.x sources on e4 (Eclipse Luna), I'm getting a return value `null` .  `layout.getFolderForView(String)`

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {


    super.createInitialLayout(layout);

    IPlaceholderFolderLayout topLeftFolder = layout.getFolderForView("com.veb.views.ModuleExplorerView"); 

    topLeftFolder.addPlaceholder("com.debugger.ui.modules.ModulesView");
    topLeftFolder.addPlaceholder("org.eclipse.debug.ui.VariableView"); 
 }
```

**NOTE : Please note that the above snippets is working well in 3.x Eclipse (Indigo) and the issue happens only at Eclipse e4 (or Luna).**

In eclipse 3.x series, the `layout` was observed to be `PageLayout`, whereas in Eclipse e4 it was `ModeledPageLayout`.

`PageLayout` itself is not present in Eclipse e4 Model, and so I'm running into issues.

How to fetch the `IPlaceholderLayout` instance for an existing view (defined in `plugin.xml`) in `e4` ?

Any alternate API exists for retrieving the same ??

Any workaround (or suggestions) will be appreciated !

Comment: Is this the entire code for the perspective factory? On a quick look at the old code I don't see how this would ever have worked as you haven't set up a folder for "com.veb.views.ModuleExplorerView"

Comment: @greg-449 : This is just a part of my old code, the folders has been already setup.

Comment: As indicated in my question, the problem arises only if I use Eclipse e4 and in my 3.x Eclipse series it was working properly.  Any workaround exists to resolve this ??  How to fetch the placeHolder for an existing `view` defined at my `plugin.xml`

Comment: @greg-449 : Hi, Any update on this issue ??     Kindly assist me in this regard, I'm currently unable to add any new placeholders (and I'm getting a `null` value if I try to do so).

Comment: I have never seen a layout that uses `getFolderForView`. It is more usual to use `createFolder`, `createPlaceholderFolder`, ...

Comment: @greg-449 :   `createFolder` & `createPlaceholderFolder`  works fine, but I need to know why `getFolderForView` fails in e4 and working fine in 3.x Eclipse series.

I need the alternate of this in e4